# json_encode on PHP return "2" instead of square bracket one time on ~300 lines (others are correct)

Tags: php, json

I've got a function who return me in json a large quantity of data. It was working good but today, an wild error appear. I have this string `}]},"2":{"trainid`  instead of this `}]},{"trainid`

There is `"2":` out of nowhere, don't know where it come from.

Here is my code (kind of)

```
$return_list = array();
$query = "SELECT * from train_users"
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $trainlist = array();

    $query2 = "Select * FROM train WHERE train_users_id = ".$row['id_user'];
            if($result2 = $mysqli->query($query2)) {
                while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $poollist[] = $row2['trainid'];
                }
            }
    for($i = 0;  $i < count($finalPoolList) ; $i++) {
        $query2 = "Select * FROM trainpassengers WHERE trainid = ".$row['id_user'];
            if($result2 = $mysqli->query($query2)) {
                while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    $row['train'][$i] = $rowPool;
                }
            }
    }
    $return_list[] = $row;
  }
}
```

Another kind of same error was this :

`"trains":{"1":{`

instead of this :

`"trains":[{`

`{"1":` replaces `[`, don't know why

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking or what the supposed problem is. Please show a complete well formatted sample, not just snippets.

Comment: it's because of structure of your array check it by printing it `print_r($return_list);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON/Javascript has two collection types: arrays and objects. Arrays are numerically indexed ordered collections:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Objects are key-value associations:

```
{ foo : 'bar', baz : 42 }
```

PHP only has one collection type: an associative ordered key-value store:

```
array('foo', 'bar' => 'baz', 42)
```

When encoding to JSON, any PHP array that has *continuous numeric indices starting at 0* is converted into a JSON array:

```
array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')  →  ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Anything else is converted to an object:

```
array(1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 3 => 'baz')  →  { "1" : "foo", "2" : "bar", "3" : "baz" }
```

Because you're creating your array like this:

```
$row['train'][$i] = $rowPool;
```

`$i` is not always starting at `0`, so you're creating arrays which are converted to objects.
Just get rid of `$i`:

```
$row['train'][] = $rowPool;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot deceze, that was where the problem came from. Regards Kisame

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, you get `"trains":{"1":{`?
This means, that trains is an Array and has different Elements.
If you print a Tree of trains, it would look like:

```
trains: {
  1: {
       First Element fo trains
     }
  2: {
       Second Element of trains
  }
}
```